# Java Graphics2D Flicker issue

Tags: java, graphics2d, flicker

I am making a tile-based rig game in java using the built in Java Graphics2D. My issue is that my screen flickers whenever the player moves around the map. The map scrolls around (meaning that the player stays at the center of the screen). It flickers when the map moves. I have already used Buffering techniques, but to no avail. My main code is below:

```
package dev.thenamegenerator.MasterQuestAlpha.display;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import dev.thenamegenerator.MasterQuestAlpha.collision.WaterCollision;
import dev.thenamegenerator.MasterQuestAlpha.entities.MainPlayer;
import dev.thenamegenerator.MasterQuestAlpha.gfx.Assets;
import dev.thenamegenerator.MasterQuestAlpha.world.MovingMap;
import dev.thenamegenerator.MasterQuestAlpha.world.World;
import dev.thenamegenerator.MasterQuestAlpha.world.WorldRenderer;

public class Board extends Canvas implements Runnable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private MainPlayer player;
    private MovingMap wholeMap;
    private World map;
    private WaterCollision watercollision;
    private WorldRenderer render;
    private int frames = 0;
    private int ticks = 0;

    Graphics2D g2d;
    public Thread thread;

    Image currentWorld;

    private int width = 480;
    private int height = 374;

    public static boolean running = false;

    public Board(){
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        if(!running)return;
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void init(){     
        Assets.init();
        map = new World();
        player = new MainPlayer(224,128);
        render = new WorldRenderer();

        watercollision = new WaterCollision(map.getStartMap(), map.getRightMap());
        watercollision.initCollision();

        render.renderWorld(map.getStartMap(), map.getRightMap());

        wholeMap = new MovingMap(render.getImage(), 0, 0);
    }

    public void tick() {
        wholeMap.move();
        watercollision.updateWaterBlocks(wholeMap.getDx(), wholeMap.getDy());
        checkCollision();
    }

    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        //CLEARS SCREEN
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        //RENDER HERE
        g2d.drawImage(wholeMap.getMapImage(), wholeMap.getX(), wholeMap.getY(), null);
        g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(), 224, 128, this);
        //END RENDER
        g2d.dispose();
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void run(){
        init();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
        double ns = 1000000000D/amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;

        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now-lastTime)/ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta>=1){
                ticks++;
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frames++;
            render();
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000){
                lastTimer+=1000;
                System.out.println("Frames: " + frames + ", ticks:" + ticks);
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void checkCollision(){
        if(player.getX() == (wholeMap.getX()-32)){
            wholeMap.resetPreviousLocation();
            watercollision.updateWaterBlocks(wholeMap.getDx(), wholeMap.getDy());
            wholeMap.setDx(0);
            wholeMap.setDy(0);
            //System.out.println("Collision Detected!");
        }
        if(player.getX() == (wholeMap.getX()+wholeMap.getWidth()-32)){
            wholeMap.resetPreviousLocation();
            watercollision.updateWaterBlocks(wholeMap.getDx(), wholeMap.getDy());
            wholeMap.setDx(0);
            wholeMap.setDy(0);
            //System.out.println("Collision Detected!");
        }
        if(player.getY() == (wholeMap.getY() - 32)){
            wholeMap.resetPreviousLocation();
            watercollision.updateWaterBlocks(wholeMap.getDx(), wholeMap.getDy());
            wholeMap.setDx(0);
            wholeMap.setDy(0);
            //System.out.println("Collision Detected!");
        }
        if(player.getY() == (wholeMap.getY() + wholeMap.getHeight())){
            wholeMap.resetPreviousLocation();
            watercollision.updateWaterBlocks(wholeMap.getDx(), wholeMap.getDy());
            wholeMap.setDx(0);
            wholeMap.setDy(0);
            //System.out.println("Collision Detected!");
        }
        if(watercollision.checkWaterCollisionX(player.getX(), player.getY())){
            wholeMap.resetPreviousLocation();
            watercollision.updateWaterBlocks(wholeMap.getDx(), wholeMap.getDy());
            wholeMap.setDx(0);
            wholeMap.setDy(0);
            //System.out.println("VIKA");
        }

    }

    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            wholeMap.keyReleased(e);
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            wholeMap.keyPressed(e);
            player.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: The timing between frames might be to small...but I'd be surprised if it was the only issue

Comment: What should I do to make the timing between frames longer? I've already tried lengthening the "Thread.sleep" line in the run method, but the problem persists. Other than that, everything else works fine.

Comment: What OS? What version of Java?

Comment: The latest version of Mac, and Java 1.8

Comment: Try using JPanel (and JFrame) instead of Canvas.

Comment: I took your base code and tested it (had to provide my own elements to be rendered) and had no (obvious issues) on Yosemite and Java 8. It might be the problem is else where in your code

Comment: I'll look more closely at my code and test it on Windows.

Comment: Is there anything else in general that I should fix and rewrite?

Comment: And thanks for taking the time out of your day to help me.

Comment: I have tested on Windows, and the problem still exists

Comment: What are potential causes for the flickering?